# Configure AG Grid autoGroupColumnDef to only show chevron with no excess whitespace

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Does anybody have experience with configuring the `autoGroupColumnDef` property for AG Grid? I am simply trying to make the default Group Column for my `treeData` grid to *only* show the expand/collapse chevron (with no group text). Below is my `autoGroupColumnDef` config and the current visual state:

```
const gridOptions: GridOptions = {
  treeData: true,
  getDataPath: (data) => data.hierarchy as string[],
  autoGroupColumnDef: {
    headerName: "",
    width: 30, // <-- gets completely ignored??
    valueFormatter: () => "",
    cellRenderer: "agGroupCellRenderer",
    cellRendererParams: {
      suppressCount: true,
    },
  },
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, I am left with a large amount of whitespace between the chevron in the group column and the data columns despite my setting an explicit `width: 30` in the config. How can I get rid of this whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use maxWidth instead of width.